# Need Help Calculating a Point in Java in 3d Space

Tags: java, trigonometry

I am building a model of a person in Java. I am having a bit of trouble getting the arms to function the way I need them to.

The arms connect to the body using the following function

```
public void PseudoChild(ModelRenderer Parent, float ParentLength, ModelRenderer Child){

float X = ParentLength * MathHelper.sin(Parent.rotateAngleX) * MathHelper.sin(Parent.rotateAngleY);
float Y = ParentLength * MathHelper.cos(Parent.rotateAngleX);
float Z = ParentLength * MathHelper.sin(Parent.rotateAngleX) * MathHelper.cos(Parent.rotateAngleY);

Child.rotationPointX = X + Parent.rotationPointX;
Child.rotationPointY = Y + Parent.rotationPointY;
Child.rotationPointZ = Z + Parent.rotationPointZ;

}
```

This function uses the Body's X and Y rotation angles to calculate where to place the arms at the shoulders. But in order to place the forearms at the end of the upper arms I need to be able to account for the x,y & z rotation angles.

I have the length of the arm, the pitch yaw and roll of the arm, how do I calculate where to place the forearm?

Thank you,

Comment: You should edit for more info, about what you want as final result. Furthermore from what i remembre when i was working with 3D maths for DirectX you can not simply say i have X Y & Z rotation, cause it change the retation according to the order you apply the 3 rotations. To do that you use quaternions

Comment: I did specify
"to place the forearms at the end of the upper arms"
Also known as a Kinematic Chain
The boy only uses pitch and yaw to rotate so it is easy to calculate where to place objects on it, but the upper arms rotate using pitch yaw and roll, so it is difficult to place the forearms at the end of the upper arms....like a person.

Comment: As i told you, i think your error is in rotation, cause you should not use a free 3D rotation as you do in 2D. But still if you do so, you need to apply exactly in the same way and the same order x,y,z rotation to each obj.

Comment: Cause if you think, you need to specify exactly, what is rotating what, how to apply wich and when. If you avoid using Matrixes and Quaternions, is like this, easy to do, but tricky. Need a whole bunch of debugging.